# django set_test_cookie fails to set cookie

Tags: python, django

## Question

Using [`set_test_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies) in a django view fails to actually set a test cookie and I can't figure out why.

### Steps to Reproduce

The actual project is much more complex than this, however, the error is reproducible in a near empty project.

#### Shell

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ pip install django
(venv)$ django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .
(venv)$ python manage.py startapp polls
```

#### settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'database.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$', 'hellodjango.polls.views.login'),
)
```

#### polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            return HttpResponse("You're logged in.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Please enable cookies and try again.")
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    return HttpResponse("Look ma, no cookies!")
```

#### Shell

```
(venv)$python manage.py runserver
```

#### Browser

Go to localhost:8000/login/ and notice that your get request does not show a response cookie with the name `testcookie` and the value `worked` as per the `set_test_cookie` [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L64).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it works! You might want to visit your website with cookies disabled and see for yourself.

#### Anyway, here's the explanation:

If you look at the source for `set_test_cookie`, you'll notice that it actually sets a variable in the current session, not a cookie or anything (at least, not directly).

Here's how it works:

1. You call `set_test_cookie`, a key of `TEST_COOKIE_NAME` and of value `TEST_COOKIE_VALUE` is added to your current session.
2. You current session was modified (check the `__setitem__` method), so [a sessionid (1) cookie will be sent](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) (2)
3. When you `POST` data in your next request, django checks whether the key `TEST_COOKIE_NAME` happens to be in your session data and has the right value.

If it does, it means we were able to retrieve your session from your request, so that the sessionid cookie we used to identify you was sent back (lest we wouldn't have been able to retrieve your session), so you must support cookies.

Hope this makes things clearer to you; if it doesn't, I think you should look into the details of how HTTP works.

#### Notes

(1) Or whatever the `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` setting sets.
(2) Actually, a sessionid cookie will be sent even if the session was not altered if the `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` setting is true

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. I, on the other hand, am just smart enough to be stupid. I read the set_test_cookie source but still was thinking browser cookie - because of the name - instead of a session variable!

Comment: Setting `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` to `True` can also make `request.session.test_cookie_worked()` return `False` in development.